# Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript

Getting the error

> Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'

in node_modules/ng2-breadcrumb/app/components/breadcrumbService.ts
I am trying to implement breadcrumb functionality in an angular2 app.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 221):

Add `"es2016"` or later to your `"lib"` array in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016"],
    ...
    "target": "es5",
    ...
  }
}
```

This should work since TypeScript 2.1.

A [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340).

## Explanation

The [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Specifications) method on `Array` is supported since ES7 (ES2016). The above will add a missing library file to compilation.

The TypeScript compiler options are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: what does this actually do?

Comment: @light24bulbs The [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Specifications) method is supported since ES7 (ES2016). The above will add a missing library file to compilation. The TypeScript compiler options are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Not sure why `es2017` and not `es2016` or `es7` is here.

Comment: I can confirm that includes works when lib is set to es2016.

Comment: Note, `es` in `es2017` should be lowercase if you're using typescript.

Comment: Checked, lib `es7` is sufficient for `includes`

Comment: you can transpile your code using es7 lib, but you have to add extra polyfill to use in runtime.

Answer (score 63):

If you don't want to change to es2016, just use `arr.indexOf(valueToCheck) !== -1`.

Answer (score 16):

Changing the compiler target to "es2016" in `tsconfig.js` should solve this issue.

Comment: The poster is using angular, hence this application will be running in the browser.  Browser support for ES2016 is paltry... at best with no support for IE11. Changing the compiler target would not be an option. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Comment: @JaredG `Array.prototype.includes` can be polyfilled, so tsc's output can be piped to babel for legacy browser support

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to call .includes() on a set rather than an array. Try calling .has() instead