# TypeScript equivalent of JavaScript includes()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Getting a TypeScript error using includes on an array element. Of course once compiled down to js it works fine but I still get the following TypeScript error:

> Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'boolean[]'

Code:

```
validAttrs() {
  let valid: boolean[] = this.required.map((value, index) => {
    if(this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute(value) === null) {
      return false;
    };
    return true;
  });
  return valid.includes(false) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `boolean[]` with `Array<boolean>`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340

Comment: @echonax What difference would that make? They are identical in meaning.

Comment: @torazaburo I think it's a typescript issue sir. Maybe they haven't implemented it yet with that type. That's why I said "try" :P

Comment: I no longer get the error so there definitely makes a diffrence

Comment: Is there some reason you would not just use `!valid.every(Boolean)`? Also, is there some reason for saying `if (b) return false; else return true;` instead of `return !b;`?

Comment: It's not a code review but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string\[\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Answer (score 3):

As far as fixing the compilation error goes, fixed the compilation issue was adding `es2016` to the `lib` option in my `tsconfig.json`. This adds the necessary declaration of `includes` on arrays.

I tried with TypeScript 2.1.4 the [suggested fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41260893/1906307) of replacing `boolean[]` with `Array<boolean>`. It made no difference whatsoever. Logically, it shouldn't make a difference because `boolean[]` and `Array<boolean>` *are the same thing*.

---

This being said, I concur with [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41261372/1906307) that the OP's code should be implemented as:

```
validAttrs() {
  return this.required.every(value => this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute(value) !== null);
}
```

Besides removing unnecessary logic, this also has the advantage that `every` stops inspecting the array as soon as the callback returns a falsy value. There's no point inspecting the rest because the return value will necessarily be `false` as soon as the callback returns a falsy value. On the other hand, the implementation in the question will *always* perform the test on all elements the of array. If the very first element fails the test, then it will inspect the rest of the array needlessly!!

Answer (score 2):

@echonax's comment worked for me.

```
validAttrs() {
  let valid: Array<boolean> = this.required.map((value, index) => {
    if(this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute(value) === null) {
      return false;
    };
    return true;
  });
  return valid.includes(false) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: I'm very doubtful that replacing `boolean[]` with `Array<boolean>` would make any difference. They are semantically identical.

Comment: OK so am 100% certain that when my code read boolean[] then it errored out on me, however when I changed it to Array<boolean> it didn't error and complied.

Comment: In the playground, when I use `boolean[]`, I get the error which you reported, namely "Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'boolean[]'". When I change this to `Array<boolean>`, I get exactly the same error, demonstrating that to TS they are the same. According to the docs, *Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use the type of the elements followed by `[]` to denote an array of that element type. The second way uses a generic array type, `Array<elemType>`*.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `includes` for what you are trying to do. Your code can simply be

```
validAttrs() {
  return this.required.every(value => this.elm.nativeElement.getAttribute(value) !== null);
}
```

This also has the advantage that it will stop checking the minute it finds the first null value.