# .includes does not exist on type 'string[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to use .includes in my component.ts file but it throws me the following error. help me in resolving the issue.

- Error

> Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'

- app.component.ts

  ```
  permissionCookie: string[]; 
  this.permissionCookie = cookieService.get("permissions").split(",");
  this.permissionFlag = this.permissionCookie.includes("22");
  ```
- ts.config

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "",
      "declaration": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "mapRoot": "./",
      "module": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
      ]
    }
  }
  ```

  this [Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string) didnt help me either

Comment: this.permissionCookie - is this an array? includes is only for arrays.

Comment: You said the solution in the link you posted didn't work yet your config doesn't use that at all. It says to use `es2016` for the target and you are not. Everything else is set to ES6 when `includes` is part of ES2016.

Comment: yes , it is...@RemyaJ

Comment: @GillesC i meant in the way i tried changing the target to es2016 and though it didnot work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string\[\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it as,

```
 private permissionCookie:Array<string>;
constructor() {
  let a = this.permissionCookie.includes("22");
  console.log(a);
}
```

tsconfig.json -->

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    // "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,
    // "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": ["jquery"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you console your this.permissionCookie after split and show ?

Comment: [ "32", "33", "21", "22" ]

Comment: not sure but Hey this worked for me  ` "lib": ["es7", "dom"] `  changed to this in my ts.config file now .includes, .splice everything works without errors. Thanks for support @RemyaJ

Comment: can u post ur config.ts file content @RemyaJ

Comment: Have added it ,you can check.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"ES2017"` to your `"lib"` array in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    ...
  }
}
```

This should work in TypeScript 2.1+.

A [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340).