# Javascript filter array with multiple objects

Tags: jquery, typescript

Hi all I have my JSON as follows

```
var autoNotifyCategories = {
"notify": [{
    "Category": "Category1",
    "Title": ["Title1", "Title2"],
    "Pending": "true"
  },
  {
    "Category": "Category2",
    "Title": ["Title1"],
    "Pending": "true"
  },
  {
    "Category": "Category3",
    "Title": ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"],
    "Pending": "true"
  },
]
```

}

I will have my filter as follows

```
var filter = {
    Category: 'Category3',
    Title: 'Title4'
};
```

At title I can pass any based on the requirement but what I need is I would like to filter exactly based on the parameters I passed and return the Pending value from the array. I tired as below but it is checking only for the Category it seems, I need to validate both category and title can some one help me, here is he fiddle I tried

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  //banner.addClass("alt")
  var autoNotifyCategories = {
    "notify": [{
        "Category": "Category1",
        "Title": ["Title1", "Title2"],
        "Pending": "true"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category2",
        "Title": ["Title1"],
        "Pending": "true"
      },
      {
        "Category": "Category3",
        "Title": ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"],
        "Pending": "true"
      },
    ]
  }
  var filter = {
    Category: 'Category3',
    Title: 'Title4'
  };
  //alert(autoNotifyCategories.notify);
  let s = autoNotifyCategories.notify.filter(function(item) {
    for (var key in filter) {
      if (item[key] === filter[key]) {
        return item.Pending;
      }

    }
  });
  alert(s[0].Pending);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code directly into your question, not just as a link to an external service.

Comment: Your problem is that you are returning the item inside your loop over those filter properties, as soon as you find the first match. You need to replace this with a flag that gets modified accordingly inside the loop, and then return the item (or not) _after_ the loop, based on that flag.

Comment: Some one has given this answer `let filtered = autoNotifyCategories.notify.filter(e => e.Category === filter.Category && e.Title.includes(filter.Title));` which is working but I am getting an error as `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'`

Comment: You can use `indexOf` instead to check whether the title contains a specific string. (Careful with what the return value of that method means.)

Comment: It is always returning value even if the condition doesn't matches

Comment: Was that regarding the suggestion to use `indexOf`, or that approach in general? If the former, then show what you tried. (But please don’t post extended codes in comments, that is hardly readable; edit your question instead, and append the new information.)

Comment: Here is the fiddle on the same https://jsfiddle.net/kbphzaev/4/

Comment: _“(Careful with what the return value of that method means.)”_

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `Title` is an array you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for validation.

```js
var autoNotifyCategories = {
  "notify": [{
      "Category": "Category1",
      "Title": ["Title1", "Title2"],
      "Pending": "true"
    },
    {
      "Category": "Category2",
      "Title": ["Title1"],
      "Pending": "true"
    },
    {
      "Category": "Category3",
      "Title": ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"],
      "Pending": "true"
    },
  ]
}

var filter = {
  Category: 'Category3',
  Title: 'Title4'
};
var filtered = autoNotifyCategories.notify.filter((obj) => {
  return (obj.Category === filter["Category"]) && (obj.Title.includes(filter["Title"]))
})

alert(filtered[0].Pending)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but as said I am getting an error in type script as `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]`

Comment: Have you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Please check your code written in JSfiddle.The array was not matched inittially.
The array should be coverted to String for comparison.

Its working now..!

```
    let s = autoNotifyCategories.notify.filter(function(item) {
    let cnt  = 0,equal = 1;
    for (var key in filter) {
      cnt++;
      equal = (item[key].toString().includes(filter[key].toString()));
      if(equal && cnt == Object.keys(filter).length){
            return item[key];
      }
    }
  });

  if(s.length){
    alert(s[0].Pending)
  }else{
    alert('Not Found');
  }
```

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3f2Lmjyj/

Comment: No luck still the same

Comment: Replace ===  by includes .Its working https://jsfiddle.net/3s86f2kg/18/

Comment: as said include is giving me the following error in type script `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171088/discussion-between-sakthikanth-and-learner).

Comment: Can we simplify this in one line, I tried with having ! symbol but didn't worked `if (item[key].toString().includes(filter[key].toString())) {
      
      }else{
       equal = 0;
      }`

Comment: Yes, we can, ie. equal = (item[key].toString().includes(filter[key].toString()))