# includes function doesn't exist on string[] when I use typescript@3.0.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

eg

```
const arr: string[] = ['a', 'b', '3'];
arr.includes('a')
```

It shows an error:

> includes function isn't exist on string[]

I wonder includes function exist on Array prototype, why not exist on `string[]`?
How can I solve this question?

Comment: what is the target version in tsconfig file?

Comment: @Madhawa If you're going to fix edits like formatting, it causes a bump, so you should try and solve all the issues with the post. There are a lot more typos and other things which could be fixed.

Comment: The includes function only exists for arrays in es7, so if you are targeting es6 you will get this error message (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

Comment: when i change es2016, it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string\[\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add "es7" to "libs" of tsconfig.json, like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es7"
    ],
...
```

Comment: thanks, when i change target es2016 or lib "es7", it all work