# Optional Chaining using indexOf?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to simplify this code:

```js
function exists(haystack?: string[]): boolean {
  if (haystack) {
    return haystack.indexOf("needle") > -1
  }

  return false
}
```

...and I was thinking I could use Optional Chaining to do so.
However, it does not work and it looks like I'm misunderstanding something...

```js
function exists(haystack?: string[]): boolean {
  return haystack?.indexOf("needle") > -1 // ERROR: Object is possibly 'undefined'. (2532)
}
```

Comment: With optional chaining your expression is *effectively* `undefined > -1` if `haystack` is `undefined`.

Comment: `return haystack?.indexOf("needle") && haystack.indexOf("needle") > -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `haystack` a default value like an empty array so that if no value is provided while calling this function, we can use empty array to prevent this `undefined` object error:

```
function exists(haystack: string[] = []): boolean {
  return haystack.indexOf("needle") > -1;
}
```

You can further improve your code by replacing `.indexOf()` with `includes()`;

```
function exists(haystack: string[] = []): boolean {
  return haystack.includes("needle");
}
```

Comment: Hmmm and without a default value, I could use this?

`return !!haystack?.includes("needle");`

Comment: @kraftwer1 It should work. See this post for a possible error and its fix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string