# Typescript: define a type as "any except type" without triggering errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type for any plain JS object:

```
type Entity = {
  [k: string]: any,
};
```

I'm incrementally adding TS to my codebase, so I'm allowing implicit any. With this type, I can do:

```
const user: Entity = ...;
user.name.includes(...);
```

However, if I want to define it as any plain JS object without object or array values:

```
type Entity = {
  [k: string]: string | number | boolean | null,
};
```

I get: `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean'.`

I also tried this, not sure if it's valid TS:

```
type Entity = {
  [k: string]: Entity[k] extends Object ? never : Entity[k];,
};
```

But same thing: `Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Is it possible to get TS to not throw errors in this case? I want it to behave as if the object value's type was `any`.

Comment: If you want it to behave as if the value type was `any`, you just assign `any` to value type. How do you see it otherwise? I mean, what is the point to assign `string | number | whatever` to values if you are anyway going to use them however you want.

Comment: I tried longer than I'm willing to admit, but I don't think it is possible without using something like a typeguard or adding some overhead. There are other people proposing things that _almost_ work, but don't apply here.

Comment: Need to set tsconfig.json to `--lib dom,es2017` Leo please check these links below, might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545329/property-includes-does-not-exist-on-type-string AND https://github.com/PatrickJS/angular-starter/issues/931#issuecomment-244001423

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone comes up with a really clever way of working around `Object` and `any` and before `not object` works, I'd recommend trying to build something like

```
type Entity = {
  name?: string;
  [key: string]: string | boolean | number | undefined;
}
```

```
type Entity = {
  name?: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

Hopefully, you can narrow down your types. In the meantime, I'd try to add more precision and safety where possible. If `Entity` comes from an external source, then you might want to consider using `unknown` type.